# Finding the maximum value in a matrix (C programming)

Tags: c

I'm learning to code in C. I've wrote the following code to find the maximum value inside a matrix, but for some reason the program would return the highest value in the first row (87), except the desired 99. I can't find the flaw in the code. Would be really happy for some help!

```
#include <stdio.h>

int Maxmin(int a[][4], int row, int col) {
  int i, j, max;
  max = a[0][0];

  for (i = 0; i < row; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < col; j++) {
      if (a[i][j] > max)
        max = a[i][j];
    }
    return max;
  }
}

void main() {
  int a[3][4] = {
    {  3, 87, 11, 23 },
    { 99, 78, 19, 44 },
    { 59, 60, 13, 14 }
  };

  int num;
  num = Maxmin(a, 3, 4);
  printf("%d\n", num);
}
```

Comment: Indent your code properly and consistently; your return statement in inside one of the loops.

Comment: why are you putting this in comment section and not in answer section?

Comment: Unbelievable, it's a beginner needing debugging suggestions NOT a typo

Answer (score 2):

Not really easy to spot as usually bugs like this are down to i & j typos.
The `return max;` is inside the row's for loop.

Move it to the end of the function and then you'll examine every row of the matrix. I actually compiled and ran this fix.

The way to discover such errors, is to either put in extra print statements, like :

```
printf( "a[%d][%d]=%d ", i, j, a[i][j]);
```

Or to step through your program with a debugger, setting a break point on the code you're interested in.

Comment: Well, it's very easy to spot when stepped through with a debugger.

Comment: I have tried to tailor the answer for a beginner, everyone makes mistakes and sometimes it's the dumb stupid ones that are hardest to find.  I actually stopped using i & j for a while in the 80's because I spent days looking for a subtle bug in a large program which was basically invisble on the poor quality print outs of that time, as i & j were almost indistinguishable.